# Define a TypeScript function that will accept an argument that is a function that could have multiple signatures?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

Looking for a way to define a function in TypeScript that will accept, as one of it's arguments, a function that may be of different signatures

```js
const foo = (a: string, b: number) => {
  //do something
}

const bar = (a: number, b: string, c: boolean) => {
  //do something
}

const myDynamicFunction = (
  str: string,
  // I tried this, but no dice
  method: ((a: string, b: number) => void) | ((a: number, b: string, c: boolean) => void), 
  num: number,
  bool?: boolean
) => {
  if (bool) {
    method(num, str, bool)
  } else {
    method(str, num)
  }
}

myDynamicFunction(
  'string', foo, 5
)

myDynamicFunction(
  'string', bar, 5, true
)
```

I tried going down the "function overloads" rabbit hole, but that just left me where I started w/ essentially the same error of unexpected number of arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'd have to cast your method, because TypeScript cant figure this one out:

```
if (bool) {
    (method as (a: number, b: string, c: boolean) => void)(num, str, bool)
  } else {
    (method as (a: string, b: number) => void)(str, num)
  }
```

Comment: Perfect.. gets rid of the "red sqwigglies" so good enough for me 

Comment: This doesn't match the OP in terms of the parameter order.

Answer (score 0):

There were some subtleties that I couldn't get my head around at first, but breaking it down finally got me there.  Typescript seems to have some difficulty disambiguating parameter types without first defining discreet type aliases.

We need to use a type predicate to determine, based on the value of `bool`, whether we are dealing with a call to a BAR like function.

When we do that, we still haven't narrowed the type of `bool` to be specifically boolean (another predicate would do the job also), but we know that's the case so we can use the `!` non-null assertion to allow it to be passed to a method that requires `boolean`.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg8nKBeKAKAhgLigZ2AJwEsA7AcwBooAjbYgVwFsqJ8BKZAPigDcB7QgCYAoUJCgAhAIIAlZGixR6TFpRq4CJClADG2Kr14AbCOmLskXPoKFCAZnWLbghXsSiEcU6agYRgAC14BbFMQVQNDPQiTNwAfKAcBCFsSCAFWbF8AoPccCRkoAG8hKFKofD86fDdRCF5bKCzAgWQkFABye0dnV3aoADJ+qFr66gioAEI2hOIklOI0oQBfG21XPChbAzkMbDwiMlVaRmY2TiKSsoB6K4FeXF4mzWXV9eBqdHwdhSVTo-UDlpdGMjDFzFximUoDc7g8nmQXkI1sQNgwQAAREDEdAMQjaGAOJwuNwoVCXUr7PYaQ7kxp+ZrYeCIeJeci0pTHZT4NlQ-RGAD8UVBpiE4IuUI8Xh89KC4SM7H5dOyAlQSko+zlhgm7EyMpVGsUjFYiLRmOxuPxhJ6xDJUPa+007UoW14lAArKKbKasTi8QTusTbWV7dTSE6PtyoG7KAQ6BBRUA)

```
type FOO = (a: string, b: number) => void
type BAR = (a: number, b: string, c: boolean) => void

function isBAR(method: any, bool: boolean | undefined): method is BAR {
    return typeof method === 'function' && bool !== undefined
}

const foo = (a: string, b: number) => {
    //do something
}

const bar = (a: number, b: string, c: boolean) => {
    //do something
}

const myDynamicFunction = (
    str: string,
    method: FOO | BAR,
    num: number,
    bool?: boolean
) => {
    isBAR(method, bool) ? method(num, str, bool!) : method(str, num)
}

myDynamicFunction('string', foo, 5)
myDynamicFunction('string', bar, 5, true)
myDynamicFunction('string', bar, 5, false)
```

Comment: yes! very cool use of type guards here

Comment: Interesting.. 

But something's not making sense to me.. 

When foo is called w/ this, the two arguments appear to be swapped.  Not sure how a string becomes a number and vice versa?
```
const foo = (a: string, b: number) => {
    console.log('foo called', a, b)
}

const bar = (a: number, b: string, c: boolean) => {
    console.log('bar called', a, b, c)
}
```

`[LOG]: "foo called",  5,  "string"`

Isn't it this kind of runtime type issue that TS is supposed to be "saving" us from? 

Comment: My bad, in the type predicate I had `typeof bool !== undefined` when it should have been `bool !== undefined`.  Answer updated.

Comment: Actually looking at this again, whilst it does disambiguate the method call so the parameters can be passed correctly, it doesn't act as a static type check for the function being passed.  It seems to accept any function signature.  One could extend the type predicate to check all of the arguments correctness, but that wouldn't be the static check I think you were hoping for.

Comment: Ok, so it does do the parameter checking, but only partially.  When the passed function has less parameters it accepts it, due to the convention that passing extra parameters is legal (the call of `method` in `myDynamicFunction` is supplying extra params which are just ignored by the receiving function).  If you pass a function that takes more parameters, it will catch that as a type error (because the method call supplies too few, which would only work if the extra params were optionals).  I suspect that this gives you some protection, but not a guarentee of correctness.

Comment: Cool solution, but it doesn't verify everything at compile-time - for example, this should error but it doesn't: `myDynamicFunction('string', bar, 5)`. I believe that in general, the interface to `myDynamicFunction` is not well-defined, so no wonder you can't express it completely in TypeScript.

Comment: I've posted another answer that aims to resolve the static checking

Answer (score 0):

Improving on my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72627802/327598).

This aims to provide static checking that the function passed to `myDynamicFunction` does have one of the expected shapes (`FOO` or `BAR`).

Note the `err[x]` methods at the end all produce compile failures, albeit with the slightly unhelpful message "cannot be assigned to 'never'"

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-Cxp34BNeLgAfjDUGw6cz8cTdsdzoEeRLWTLy3zhdoEG4LFY5CDSmxynwHcJ+iMed2xlMQlFBLKhAaqCWMlWIfCRlY7HFhLK7wEqCUlHRi8MQMZhKmdsMOGgU7QHi88+ae+XE7XweaqF3ikYh7Kx4gp+gq8fAXwXgAHcoAAIhgdBgHQQxQKDGYYVqMMAAY5FrONs0tXMbCEBhdX1Q1jVNboFipdFNEVJFeEoABWRlcL1A0jRNM0flIgNSEVeUaMoAg6AgOi8MYwiWJI9oyLITiOW4xFoLPRlYXhLUWHwABGLl-QFPlCimM4rBaCwihmej8KYojzWINiBUVZSVOk2xZP4hTWSU-B8AAJnU-lNF0-h9LFIzBII5jiNcSzyMoZS3LshzGU1O1XIAZhRHzBHxbScMC0yRNCsT2OsxLop-WLFPi-AABZPJ5FRqA0zRVWwbSUr8wyMoYoKzNY3KrIi1yysKuSnIRZTqMqnFqrUcTBWHGJKFDUImrSgK2qykKLK68LSuo-rHKAA)

```
type FOO = (a: string, b: number) => void
type BAR = (a: number, b: string, c: boolean) => void

function isFOO(method: any, bool: boolean | undefined): method is FOO {
    return typeof method === 'function' && bool === undefined
}

function isBAR(method: any, bool: boolean | undefined): method is BAR {
    return typeof method === 'function' && bool !== undefined
}

const foo = (a: string, b: number) => {
    console.log('foo', a, b)
}

const bar = (a: number, b: string, c: boolean) => {
    console.log('bar', a, b, c)
}

const myDynamicFunction = <T extends FOO | BAR>(
    str: string,
    method: T & (Parameters<T> extends Parameters<FOO> ? T : Parameters<T> extends Parameters<BAR> ? T : never),
    num: number,
    bool?: boolean
) => {
    if (isBAR(method, bool)) {
        method(num, str, bool!)  
    } else if (isFOO(method, bool)) {
        method(str, num)        
    } else {
        throw "Fatal"
    }
}

type T0 = Parameters<FOO>


myDynamicFunction('string', foo, 5)
myDynamicFunction('string', bar, 5, true)
myDynamicFunction('string', bar, 5, false)

const err1 = (a: string, b: {}): void => {}
myDynamicFunction('string', err1, 5, false)
const err2 = (a: string): void => {}
myDynamicFunction('string', err2, 5, false)
const err3 = (): void => {}
myDynamicFunction('string', err3, 5, false)
const err4 = (a: number, b: string, c: {}): void => {}
myDynamicFunction('string', err4, 5, false)
const err5 = (a: number, b: string, c: boolean, d: any): void => {}
myDynamicFunction('string', err5, 5, false)
```